How to capture the path of an empty JSON file in a PySpark streaming job?
I'm processing JSON files in a streaming job using PySpark. I need to capture the path of the file, even if it's empty, so that I can log that it wasn't processed correctly.
Here's the code I'm using:
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    logger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("myLogger")
    
    microBatchOutputDF = df.withColumn("file_path", input_file_name())
    microBatchOutputDF.show()

# Reading the JSON files in a streaming job
df = spark.readStream \
    .option("multiLine", True) \
    .schema(SCHEMA_TABLE) \
    .format("json") \
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) \
    .load("s3a://raw/*")

# Writing to console with foreachBatch
qry = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
    .start()

qry.awaitTermination()

The issue is that when the JSON file is empty (only containing []), the input_file_name() method does not return the file name, and the resulting DataFrame contains no rows.
Here are the log messages I'm getting:
24/08/24 14:06:03 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: /tmp/temporary-329d35a8-7298-4cad-9bcf-658b236fb249. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
24/08/24 14:06:03 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
24/08/24 14:06:04 WARN __main__: BATCH ID: 0
24/08/24 14:06:04 WARN __main__: Batch is empty
+---+---------+
| id|file_path|
+---+---------+

I expect to return the file path of the file through the batch DataFrame, even if it is empty.
I've already tried using the input_file_name function, but when the file is empty, nothing is added, so I'm unable to capture the file name to indicate that it encountered an issue. I also tried using .withColumn("file_path", col("_metadata.file_path")), but I still couldn't return the file path of the file
